# One page but content changing based on URL and Database with reactjs (MERN stack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Hello guys and sorry for my English

let's say I have page1 has content in the database, and page2 has different content in a database, but page1 and page2 share the same template I just want to change the content based on the URL or id and if a user request page2 URL he will get the content for the page2 and same for other pages

and I am new to MERN Stack so give me simple solutions :)

I am not sure how to do it and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to use something called a router. The most popular router for react is the community built `react-router-dom`. This router allows you to very easily manage different routes in your application, as well as URL arguments.

To install it, run the following command:

```
npm i --save react-router-dom
```

The setup is usually done in your `App.js` file, or the file that is considered as ther `root` component in your application. Here is what you need to import:

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```

And here is how you'd define your different routes:

```
export default function App() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/posts">
            <PostsContainer />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/post/:id"> // the `:id` tells the router that this is a URL argument.
            <Post />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  )
}
```

Finally, the way you access the `URL argiments` in your components can vary, but lately with the integration of hooks into most applications, you will see a lot of people use the `useParams` custom hook which is exported from `react-router-dom`.

Here is how that would look inside of a component:

```
const Post = props => {
    const params = useParams()

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {params.id} // will render the url parameter with the key of id.
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Additionally, within this component you can make an API call to fetch the post with the specific ID, or filter it out of your global store if you are using some sort of global state management framework or tool.

Visit [this link](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for additional and up to date info in case you are reading this in the future or need more info.